# What if Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization fails?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, bilinear-form, gram-schmidt

Let $f$ be a symmetric bilinear form.Let $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}$ be a basis.Now we know that we can find an orthogonal basis by Gram Schmidt process which is as follows:

$\beta_1=\alpha_1$ and $\beta_n=\alpha_n-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{f(\alpha_n,\beta_j)}{f(\beta_j,\beta_j)}\beta_j$.But what happens if $f(\beta_j,\beta_j)=0$ for some $j$.

Should we modify this process in order to avoid such situation?Can someone give me a basis where such situation arises?

Comment: You want positive definite for the formula you write. See [here](https://www.math.unl.edu/~bharbourne1/M818Spr05/OthogonalBasisAlgorithmsRev.pdf) for a generalisation.

Comment: @Mentos Can you give an example where this generalized process is applied?I mean a numerical problem.